# openssl ruby, add an additional ssl certificate (i.e. don't replace old ones)

Tags: ruby, ssl, openssl, http.rb

I'm facing troubles with an API call I do [with HTTP gem](https://github.com/httprb/http), the https server I need to call has a certificate created by a CA that is valid but the root certificate is not present in the CA bundle of the server (which I have no rights to change).

I have certificate and intermediaries for the server, and can make it work with configuring `SSL_CERT_FILE` as env file, though this replaces in openssl the other certificates, so with this file only this specific API works, and nothing else.

I'm looking for a way to include the certificate globally so that all my calls work.

I managed to have successful ssl connections on a *per call level*, but it's really not ideal, and I'd like a global solution.

here's how I managed to do it:

```
store = OpenSSL::X509::Store.new
store.set_default_paths
store.add_file('ssl_certificates/ca_certificate.pem')
ssl_ctx = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new.tap do |ctx|
  ctx.set_params(
    cert_store: store
  )
end

HTTP.post("https://<the api server with the non recognised ssl certificate>.com", ssl_context: ssl_ctx)
HTTP.post("https://google.com", ssl_context: ssl_ctx)
```

The problem with this is that it's per call. I'd like to have it globally, I can set it globally via `SSL_CERT_FILE` environment variable, but in that case all other certificates are removed, and nothing else works.

any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: Try the inverse? Bundle the system certs with your SSL_CERT_FILE and use that rather than bundling your certs with the system certs, since you can't edit the system certs.